# Program can't start because dll is missing

Tags: windows-7, dll, regsvr32

Any executable that I attempt to run on this laptop pops up an error stating `The program can't start because LPK.dll is missing from your computer.  Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.`

I have tried doing `regsvr32 lpk.dll` from within system32, but that returns the error `The module "lpk.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DLLRegisterServer was not found.  Make sure that "lpk.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.`  I was able to copy the DLL file from a working computer, but I get the same issue.

How would I go about registering this DLL?  Or, alternatively, which program would I have to reinstall to get the DLL to work again?

The system is Windows 7 Professional 64-bit with Service Pack 1.  I would really like not to reinstall the OS, but at this point, I'm about ready to.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249873

Comment: Maybe this topics should be linked together http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897685/how-do-i-register-a-dll-on-windows-7-64-bit

Comment: @TheSAS Thanks, but that doesn't really help.  Both the regsvr and the dll are in the same folder (system32).  When I try doing the sysWOW64 to register the dll, I get regsvr telling me that lpk.dll is missing from my computer.  This isn't an issue of 32- vs 64-bit implementation.

Comment: note that many dlls are not system registrable, and when you attempt to regsvr32 them, the error you posted is the standard response. also, copying system dlls between computers is a bad bet, unless you can confirm that the file is of exactly the same version on both boxes.

Comment: @FrankThomas That might be the issue I ran into with copying, then.  I copied from Win7 Ultimate 64-bit.  I did make a backup first, I'll try restoring that file and regsrv'ing again.

Comment: I don't believe that dll supports registration. most don't.

Answer (score 1):

run cmd as administrator and run `sfc/scannow`.

Looks like corrupted system file.

Comment: Note, be sure to close any programs you have open before running a system file check.

Comment: Attempting to run the command `sfc /scannow` returns `The program can't start because LPK.dll is missing from your computer.  Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.`  I ran scandisk, and that found some corrupted sectors, so how would I fix that?  I did copy the new dll after I ran scandisk.

Comment: `chkdsk -R c:` will attempt a disk scan with bad sector check on the c drive. since it will likely be mounted, you will probably be prompted to perform the scan on next boot automatically. then just reboot.

Comment: I apologize, that's what I ran, not scandisk.

Comment: did you use the -R switch? -R or -B are required to search for bad blocks. also note that chkdsk and sfc do entirely different things. I've seen corobboration that the `sfc /SCANNOW` has fixed other folks problems with missing language pack dlls. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/how-to-reinstall-lpkdll/3a61ce98-ba4a-4edd-9acf-e7b7e52e38c3 so I'm surprised it gave you that error.

Comment: Did you try rebooting into recovery/repair mode? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-vista/advanced-startup-options-including-safe-mode

Comment: boot in safe mode, then execute the above commands and then try windows updates. Because you can't run any executable, updates seems to be only way. In safe mode, also try running antivirus